# Parsing data with fluentd

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, fluentd

I've fluentd with elasticsearch running and I'm forwarding logs from several Unix machines using rsyslog (basically forwarding all logs).

It works great, except I don't have any control over the data. What I want is to be able to tag certain values. Right now, everything is in @message. Say I have logs from apache coming to fluentd. I would like to use Kibana to look at the traffic (per ip, per type of file, response, etc.).

I don't know if this can be done in Kibana directly or it has to be parsed in fluentd.
How should I go about this? I've seen examples of different logs settings, but when it comes to web servers, they all tail the log file. I can't do that, because it's a remote server.

Also, I have different services that I would like to get important stats from (sql, web, mail...).

Note: I'm forwarding the logs with rsyslog.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the maintainers for Fluentd.

Do you think you can share your Fluentd configuration file as well as an example line from your log?

> Also, I have different services that I would like to get important stats from (sql, web, mail...).

- For SQL, there is https://github.com/frsyuki/fluent-plugin-sql
- For web, you can use one of the language-specific loggers (look under Tutorial on http://docs.fluentd.org)
- For mail, I am not aware of a plugin that handles this yet. I encourage you to ask our mailing list.

Comment: I have the default configuration that comes with fluentd. I've enabled syslog (I think it's commented by default) and then on my apache server I've forwarded the logs directly from rsyslog.

They are fine. I can see them in Kibana / Elasticsearch. What I want is to parse the information similar to this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/content/uploads/2013/09/Screen-Shot-2013-09-18-at-3.17.47-PM.png

Right now I have timestamp, host, ident and message. I would like to have clientIP, response, request, agent... similar to the above screenshot. I'm not sure if I need extra plugins or what...

Comment: Sorry for being late here. If you can update Fluentd (I believe v0.10.50), in_syslog can support arbitrary text with `format <regexep>`.

Answer (score 0):

For mail there is alreay work on that area.
https://gist.github.com/mikeda/d9f800c1a5aa73e125cb/raw/0a87cbbf4b49218fb7f97b3b9dc8cabfadbf9df6/in_maillog_tail.rb